# How to add OpenSL ES to QT project on android?

Tags: android, qt

I added OpenSL ES source code from a [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio) .

The C++ code compiles, but the app does not link on Android. What lib should I add to my .pro file?

```
android {

    LIBS += <what is the name of libopensles?>
}
```

there is in the sample CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(native-audio-jni, ... OpenSLES)
```

but OpenSLES does not work with QT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is

```
LIBS += -lOpenSLES
```

I simply forgot '-l' prefix.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.